# Callback function in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, callback

The test function is binded to a button click event.I am new to jquerymobile and I am trying to get a JSON response .I have done what the JQUERY doc says but the callback function isn't getting called.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

```
function test(evt) {

    // addNote($('#title').val(),$('#note').val());
    alert("hello");// <----This alert is displayed

    $.get("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2502265",{}, function (data) {
        alert("testing");//<--This alert is NOT displayed
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);//<--This alert is NOT displayed
    }, "json");   

    alert("Hello");//// <----This alert is displayed
}
```

Comment: Check the javascript console. I suspect cross-site policies error.

Comment: Ways around Cross-Domain-Policy. **1)** Use JSONP, this is built-into jQuery but requires the output from the external-server to be in the JSONP format (which is JSON wrapped in a function). **2)** Use a server-side script on your domain to do the cross-domain bit. Basically creating a repeater that gets the data from the external-domain and then puts it back out for your domain. This topic has been discussed time and time again, so you'll find a ton of good info if you search StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a request from a different domain, because of the same origin policy.

You can make a JSONP request to a different domain, but the problem is that the web server that you are calling is returning JSON, not JSONP. However, I have just put up a JSON/JSONP proxy that you can use. It will make a request to the URL that you specify, convert it to JSONP and return it.

Call the proxy and put the Yahoo URL in the `url` parameter, and change the data type to `"jsonp"`:

```
$.get("http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=weather.yahooapis.com%2fforecastjson%3fw=2502265",{}, function (data) {
  ...
, "jsonp");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bwZMZ/

Information page: http://jsonp.guffa.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `àlert("hello")` is expected to fire before any of the others. The handler will be called at some point in time if the call succeds.

However that's unlikely to happen due to cross-site policies. If you look in the development console you might see something like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2502265&_=1348150852704. Origin http://stackoverflow.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

if you wish to add a handler for errors you can do that as well

simply extend the code to

```
$.get("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2502265",{}, function (data) {
alert("testing");//<--This alert is NOT displayed
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);//<--This alert is NOT displayed
}, "json").fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

notice the .fail after your original code. The function provided will be called in case of an error in the communication with the remote server

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your page isn't located at the site http://weather.yahooapis.com. You're not allowed to do ajax call to get data from an arbituary site, except your own site( from which your html page is downloaded), that's called same origin policy! If you want to fetch data from other site, you should use json-rpc,i.e. create a script tag dynamically and set the src attribute to the address from where you're gonna fetch the data. If that site supports such a protocal, it will return the requested data as a js snippet, and invoke the call back as your set as the GET parameter.

Comment: So , if i want to "GET" an arbitrary page like "google.com" with JS ,it isn't possible right ? What if the server side does not have any such features? What if I am locked into using jquery and javascript ??  Is there any other in which I can use Jquery and also make no changes to the server side to accomplish this ??

Comment: @user38923 - For normal html page it's simply impossible to do cross-site ajax, that's all for the safety. Imagine you wrote a web app, linked some third party js files as your libraries, if the cross-site ajax were allowed, the code resides in the third party js would be able to collect the password of YOUR user and transfer it to THEIR sites - that's unacceptable. Remember, the GET request not only fetchs data, it aslo submits user-side info as it's params. You just can't do this kind of GET on normal pages, unless you're writing a browser addon, which grants your other privileges.